# Gfci on 220v air conditioner unit outside?

Tags: gfci, 240v

I need to run a line to a new ac unit outside. I figured I should only need 2 hots and a ground to supply the 220, but do I need to install a gfci breaker?  I am running conduit on side of house.

Comment: Depends on code, which depends on jurisdiction and other factors. Is this a hardwired unit or plug-in? If plug-in, new code likely requires GFCI. If hardwired, probably not. Also, you likely have 240 not 220 but that is not going to change the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Not yet

States which adopted NEC 2020 and didn't amend it otherwise (Michigan), will require GFCI on 240V hardwired appliances as of 1 Jan 2023.

So get that permit pulled now. The date of the code you must follow is decided by your permit pull date.

Comment: Agreed Harp.  The 2020 code will require GFCI on practically everything, which I think is stupid and expensive, but it is what it is.    Lets see...a$10 breaker vs a $50 breaker ....hmmmm  maybe the manufacturers have something to do with this.

Comment: Note that this answer may get mooted by a TIA to the Code -- the issues with air conditioners not playing nice with GFCI have escalated to that level already

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel *one would hope so*.  Motors and GFCIs still don't play well together.  Honestly if I made refrigerators, I would design the cord entry to have a void space about a 4" cube.  If a customer complained of GFCI trips I would send them a new cord assembly which contained an isolation transformer that fit in that void space.